# equivalent norms on vector space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, p-adic-number-theory

For $(F,\left \| . \right \|)$ is a field with local compact norm and $V$ is a vector space over F.

Can we have all norms on $V$ are equivalent?

Comment: What is a "local compact norm"? And is it on F or on V?

Comment: All norms are equivalent for finite-dimensional vectors spaces. This does not hold, however, in case of infinite number of dimensions .

Comment: thanks for your answer @Vlad